# How to optimize selecting one random row from a set acquired by JOIN

Tags: postgresql

Query in English:

- Retrieve a random row from **stuff**.
- row is not mentioned in done.
- row belongs to the highest* scored **friend**.
  *if no rows that belong to highest scored **friend** are found, take the next **friend**, an so on.

My current query takes too long to complete, because it is randomly ordering all **stuff**, while it should randomly order batch after batch.

Here is an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b016a/6) with tables and data.

My query:

```
WITH ordered_friends AS (SELECT *
                         FROM friends
                         ORDER BY score DESC)
SELECT s.stuff_id
FROM ordered_friends
  INNER JOIN (SELECT *
              FROM stuff
              ORDER BY random()) AS s ON s.owner = ordered_friends.friend
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM done
    WHERE done.me = 42
          AND done.friend = s.owner
          AND done.stuff_id = s.stuff_id
)
-- but it should keep the order of ordered_friends (score)
-- it does not have to reorder all stuff
-- one batch for each friend is enough until a satisfying row is found.    
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT s.stuff_id
FROM friends
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT stuff_id
                       FROM stuff
                       WHERE stuff.owner = friends.friend
                         AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                                        FROM done
                                        WHERE done.me = 42
                                        AND done.friend = stuff.owner
                                        AND done.stuff_id = stuff.stuff_id
                                       )
                       ORDER BY random()
                       LIMIT 1
                      ) s
ORDER BY friends.score DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The following indexes would make it fast:

```
CREATE INDEX ON friends(score);          -- for sorting
CREATE INDEX ON stuff(owner);            -- for the nested loop
CREATE INDEX ON done(stuff_id, friend);  -- for NOT EXISTS
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is one problem though: it does not filter out **stuff_id**s mentioned in table **done**.

Comment: I've extended your answer by adding the `NOT EXISTS` part. Here's the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/12f5f/6). Please point out any possible improvements.

Comment: Right, sorry. I have added it to the answer.